# How do I create a validation that checks if at least one of multiple booleans is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have a Rails 3.2 app that manages tasks.  Here tasks are being assigned to users.  The task model has multiple user variables that are booleans.  How would I add a validation to say that at least one user is set to true?

Original:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :user1, :user2, :user3, :user4:
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :is_assigned


  def is_assigned
    if #AT_LEAST_ONE_USER_IS_TRUE
      errors.add("The task must be assigned to at least one user.")
    end
  end

end
```

Edited:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :user1, :user2, user3, :user4

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validate :is_assigned

  def is_assigned
    unless @user1 || @user2 || @user3 || @user4
      errors.add(:user1, "The task must be assigned to at least one user.")
    end
  end

end
```

I'm getting closer I think but this does not work.  The error seems to always appear.

Also it looks like errors.add requires another variable.  How do I give it all users instead of just user1?

Comment: You're logic seems backwards.  You are adding the error if at least one user is true instead of not at least one user is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being my final solution:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :user1, :user2, user3, :user4

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validate :is_assigned

  def is_assigned
    unless user1 || user2 || user3 || user4
      errors[:base] << "The task must be assigned to at least one user."
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if at least one user is true:

```
if @user1 || @user2 || @user3 || @user4
```